# Proof of self-adjointness of negative Laplacian on an interval

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators

Consider the negative Laplacian $-\Delta:=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $L^2(0,1)$ with domain $$D(-\Delta)=\{f\in H^2(0,1)\,:\,f(0)=f(1)=0\}.$$ How does one prove that $-\Delta:L^2(0,1)\supset D(-\Delta)\to L^2(0,1)$ is a self-adjoint operator? I know how to show symmetry, but I don't know which way to go after.

Comment: You will have to show that for each $g\in L^2(0,1)$ there exist solutions $f_1,f_2\in D(-\Delta)$ of the differential equations $-f_1'' - if_1 = g$ and $-f_2'' + if_2 = g$.

Answer (score 0):

This operator is not a self-adjoint!

$T:=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$  on  $ L^2(0,1)$ such that
 $D(T)=\{f\in H^2(0,1)\,:\,f(0)=f(1)=0\}.$

let $\psi \in D(T^*)$ and $    \varphi \in D(T) $ so 
$\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle =   \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle          $

which mean

$\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}  -\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dx^2} \psi = \int_{0}^{1}  -\varphi \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} =  \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle$

than we have $ \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} \in L^2(0,1) \Rightarrow  \psi \in H^2(0,1) \quad and \quad T^* \psi=-\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$

inversely let $  \psi \in H^2(0,1) \quad  and \quad \varphi \in D(T)$  so 
 $\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}  -\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dx^2} \psi = \int_{0}^{1}  -\varphi \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} =  \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle$ 
and we conclude that $ \psi \in D(T^*)$

finly $T^*=-\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$ and $ D(T^*)= H^2(0,1)$